# PCF and PWS on premises license details

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotaltracker, pivotal-web-services

Can any one help me to understand the on premises licensing details and price  for setting up the Pivotal Cloud Foundry(PCF) and Pivotal Web Services (PWS)?

Answer (score 1):

**Pivotal Web Services** is a hosted solution, and can not be installed on premises.

**Pivotal Cloud Foundry** can be run on premises, and you can get licensing details by following the "Contact" link at http://pivotal.io